# Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my Symfony 5 project, I am trying to delete an entity, as well as its children, but I have this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM parametres_admin
> WHERE id = ?' with params [34]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
> update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`testApp`.`entreprise`, CONSTRAINT `FK_D19FA6019935CA7` FOREIGN KEY
> (`parametres_admin_id`) REFERENCES `parametres_admin` (`id`))

However, it seems to me that I have configured my entity correctly?

I want to delete this one

**Entreprise**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EntrepriseRepository::class)
 */
class Entreprise
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="entreprise", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=ParametresAdmin::class, inversedBy="entreprise", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $parametresAdmin;

//...
```

**ParametresAdmin**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ParametresAdminRepository::class)
 */
class ParametresAdmin implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Entreprise::class, mappedBy="parametresAdmin", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $entreprise;

    //...
```

In the **Entreprise** entity, I put `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` for **parametresAdmin** relation, to remove **ParametresAdmin** when removing **Entreprise** row.
And in my **ParametresAdmin** entity, I put `cascade={"persist"}` for **entreprise** relation. Not `, cascade={"persist", "remove"}` to be sure you don't get any mistakes. (I put it on before, but I already had this error, so I removed it but it didn't change anything)

Comment: Thank about it.  You have a 1:1 relation between enterprise and parametersAdmin.  So you can't delete parameteraAdmin without deleting enterprise as well.  If you did then you will end up with a enterprise entity pointing to a non-existent param entity.  If you need to keep the enterprise entity then you need to null out it's param relation before attempting to delete param.

Comment: So if I want to delete a Company, is there no way to automate everything using doctrine annotations? I will have to do it manually with PHP, step by step?

Comment: If you always want to delete enterprise when param is deleted then cascade remove should do the trick.  Though it seems like you already tried that?

Comment: Yes I tried that but I've the error that I noticed in my first post